# Implement jTable from Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, loops, arraylist, jtable

I have an ArrayList containing 100 values.

```
al = "AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF"... upto 100 values
```

I need to insert these values in a jTable having 2 columns and 50 rows i.e.

```
col1   col2  
AA     BB   
CC     DD  
EE     FF  
...    ...
```

upto 50 rows

How do I get that (preferably using loops)? Need a generic solution because number of elements or rows can vary.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html ? there's a couple of aproaches explained there, what is not clear?

Comment: Thanks but I need to populate and assign each field value(al.get(i)) using loop. I read the approaches in your link and also checked http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaJTable.htm

Comment: There's no need to use a loop you just need to set your TableModel properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd simply convert the arraylist in an 2 dimensional array ...

somethin like that

```
public void convertToArray(){
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < entrys.length; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            entrys[j][i] = list.get(count++);
        }
    }
}
```

then create the table

```
    String[] header = {"col1", "col2"};
    table = new JTable(entrys, header);
```

and add to frame etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need . I know this may not be the optimized way, Still try this:

```
package App;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class JtableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

List list, oddList, evenList;
String col_names[] = {"First", "Second"};

public JtableModel(List list) {
    this.list = list;

}

public void myFormatting(){

    this.oddList = new ArrayList();
    this.evenList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            this.evenList.add(list.get(i));
        } else {
            this.oddList.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}



@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return evenList.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return col_names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            try {
                return evenList.get(rowIndex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        case 1:
            try {
                return oddList.get(rowIndex);
            } catch (Exception  e) {
               //find out how you can validate this 

            }
    }

    return new String();
}
}
```

And the Snippet of java File generate with NetBeans :

```
 public class JtableDemo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JtableDemo
 */
public JtableDemo() {
    initComponents();
    fillTbl();
}

public void fillTbl(){
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.add("AA");
    arr.add("BB");
    arr.add("CC");
    arr.add("DD");
    arr.add("EE");

    JtableModel tableModel = new JtableModel(arr);
    tableModel.myFormatting();
    jTable1.setModel(tableModel);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Dividing the original `arr` in two sublists is completely unnecessary and a waste of memory and time.

Answer (score 0):

More or less :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


 public class NewClass extends JFrame {

private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private String headers[] = {"col1","col2"};
String[] data = {"AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF","GG","HH","II","JJ","KK","LL","MM","NN","OO","PP","QQ","RR"};

public NewClass() {

    model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);

    table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(model);

    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    insert();

    add(scroll, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void insert(){  
 ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ar.add(data[i]);
    }

   for (int i=0;i<(ar.size()/2);i++) {                 
    model.addRow(new Object[] { String.valueOf(ar.get(2*i)) ,  String.valueOf(  ar.get((2*i)+1))                                });

  }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
new NewClass();
    }
   }
```

[image]